# Counter for handlebars #each

Tags: javascript, templates, handlebars.js, template-engine

In Handlebars, say I have a collection of `names`. How can I do

```
{{#each names}}
{{position}}
{{name}}
{{/each}}
```

where `{{position}}` is 1 for the first name, 2 for the second name, etc.? Do I absolutely have to store the position as a key in the collection?

Answer (score 43):

You can do this with the built-in Handlebars @index notation:

```
{{#each array}}
  {{@index}}: {{this}}
{{/each}}
```

@index will give the (zero-based) index of each item in the given array.

Please note for people using Handlebars with the Razor view engine you must use the notation @@index to avoid compilation errors.

For more built-in helpers see http://handlebarsjs.com/

Comment: @algorithmicCoder this answer looks good to me. Does it work for you? Please accept it if so, for clarity. Thanks!

Comment: This would show "0" for the first name but OP wanted it to show "1". serg's answer registers a helper to provide a more complete solution.

Comment: Works but starts from 0

Answer (score 26):

```
Handlebars.registerHelper("counter", function (index){
    return index + 1;
});
```

Usage:

```
{{#each names}}
    {{counter @index}}
    {{name}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Since it actually augments by one any number, not only `@index`, I should name it `augment`, `plusone`, `plus1` - anyway something else by `counter`. Not `p1`, it remembers me P2....

Answer (score 5):

While you can't do this with any native Handlebars helper, you can create your own. You can call `Handlebars.registerHelper()`, passing it a string with the name you want to match (position), and a function that would return the current position count. You can keep track of the position number in the closure where you call `registerHelper`. Here is an example of how you can register a helper called `position` that should work with your template example.

JavaScript:

```
// Using a self-invoking function just to illustrate the closure
(function() {
    // Start at 1, name this unique to anything in this closure
    var positionCounter = 1;

    Handlebars.registerHelper('position', function() {
        return positionCounter++;
    });

    // Compile/render your template here
    // It will use the helper whenever it seems position
})();
```

Here is a jsFiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/willslab/T5uKW/1/

While helpers are documented on [handlebarsjs.com](http://handlebarsjs.com/), this took some effort for me to figure out how to use them. Thanks for the challenge, and I hope that helps!

Comment: try to add position multiple timein same div/block

Answer (score 2):

only you have to use {{@index}}

example:

```
{{#.}}
<li class="order{{@index}}"> counter: {{@index}}</li>
{{/.}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my preferred solution. Register a helper that extends the context to include your position property automatically. Then just use your new block helper (ex. #iter) instead of #each.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('iter', function (context, options) {
    var ret = "";

    for (var i = 0, j = context.length; i < j; i++) {
        ret += options.fn($.extend(context[i], {position: i + 1}));
    }

    return ret;
});
```

Usage:

```
{{#iter names}}
    {{position}}
    {{name}}
{{/iter}}
```

adapted from http://rockycode.com/blog/handlebars-loop-index/

Answer (score 0):

you can get value just from index inside the list.

```
{{#each list}}
    @index
{{/each}}
```

Comment: how to get the length of list ?

Comment: what is the use case?
if you just want to iterate over list then each function will do the work or if you want to apply other operations based on length then just register a helper function and return length of list from it.
let me know if you are asking something else and I'm unable to understand or any other query you have.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
{{#each posts}}
    <tr>               
       <td>{{@index}} </td>
       <td>{{name}}</td>
    </tr>    
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Current method,

Since Handlebars API V2 they already include an `@number`
It's basically an index of the iterator start with 1.

So, This is what you could have done.

```
{{#foreach names}}
{{@number}}
{{name}}
{{/foreach}}
```

Reference: https://ghost.org/docs/api/v3/handlebars-themes/helpers/foreach/

Comment: This may work with Ghost but not with latest version of Handlebars.js

Answer (score 0):

You can count in like this:

```
{{#each nodeArray}}
<li>
    <h3>{{@index}} {{name}}</h3>
    <p>{{shortDescription}}</p>
</li>
{{/each}}
```

Output:
[image]