# Getting index counter in nested loop of embers handlebar

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js, counter, nested-loops

I followed http://mozmonkey.com/2014/03/ember-getting-the-index-in-each-loops/ blog post to add index counter through helper. This works perfectly fine with single each loop. But when i use it with nested each loop the value gets repeated. Example :

```
{{#each item in data}}
    {{#eachIndexed record in item.innerdata}}
       {{index_1}}
    {{/eachIndexed}}
{{/each}}
```

I have two objects in data and two objects in each innerdata. Expected result is

`1 2 3 4`

but I'm getting

`1 2 1 2`

How do i get the expected result? My handlebars version is 1.1.2 and ember version is 1.6.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your data is:

```
[
  {innerdata: ['foo', 'bar']},
  {innerdata: ['foo', 'bar']}
]
```

Then it's working as intended because it's an index not a counter.

```
{{#each item in data}}
    Outer Index: {{index_1}}<br>
    {{#eachIndexed record in item.innerdata}}
       Inner Index: {{index_1}}<br>
    {{/eachIndexed}}
{{/each}}
```

Would output:

> Outer Index: 1
>   Inner Index: 1
>   Inner Index: 2
>   Outer Index: 2
>   Inner Index: 1
>   Inner Index: 2

If you want to count the number of iterations, you could try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15376389/29347

```
(function() {
  var positionCounter = 1;

  Handlebars.registerHelper('position', function() {
    return positionCounter++;
  });
})();
```

Which gives you:

```
{{#each item in data}}
    {{#eachIndexed record in item.innerdata}}
       {{position}}
    {{/eachIndexed}}
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Nested each blocks may access the interation variables via depth based
>   paths. To access the parent index, for example, {{@../index}} can be
>   used.

Source: http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html

Comment: `@index` is zero based, it also would just output the same thing as in his example if his list consists of two nested lists of length 2.